# How to get my UL have the next dive right under it instead of leaving a huge space

Tags: html, css

In this codepen: http://codepen.io/audn/pen/oBzOPK

You can see that the UL has this weird spacing between it, can anyone tell me why? I'm trying to have something next to it, but it makes it hard when it leaves this weird spacing.

HTML:

```
<nav class="bg-white">
    <ul class="nav-top wrapper">
        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/" title="HOME" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/pc.php" title="PC PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">PC list</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/ps4.php" title="PS4 PRICE LIST" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">PS4 list</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/certified.php" title="CERTIFIED LIST" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">Certified list</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/faq.php" title="FAQ" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">FAQ</span>
            </a>

        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="#" class="nav-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-staff">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">Staff</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-top">
            <a href="/donate.php" title="DONATE" class="nav-top">
                <i class="fa fa-paypal" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><span class="meny-text">Donate</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="what" style="background-color: black; width: 100%; color: white; padding: 32px;">heh</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
.nav-top {
    background:red;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
}
li a.nav-top {
    color:#34495e;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
}
li a.nav-top:hover {
    background-color:#f1f2f3;
    color:#1798e5;
}
li.nav-top {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
    .nav-top {
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction:normal;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;
        width:100%;
        line-height:10px;
    }
    a.nav-top {
        padding:5px;
    }
}
@media(min-width:700px) {
    .meny-text {
        margin-left:10px;
    }
}
.header {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.bg-white {
    background:white;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    display:none !important;
}
.item-prices {
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.item-prices > div {
    margin:5px;
}
li a.nav-top {
    color:#34495e;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
}
li a.nav-top:hover {
    background-color:#red;
    color:#1798e5;
}
li.nav-top {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}
@media(max-width:700px) {
    .nav-top {
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction:normal;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
        justify-content:center;
        width:100%;
        line-height:10px;
    }
    a.nav-top {
        padding:5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome, it has a default margin size of 1 em for UL elements.

`-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
 -webkit-margin-after: 1em;`

to get rid of it, you can add `margin: 0` to your `.nav-top` element.